# Complicated unique constraints in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, index, unique-constraint

I have a table `transactions` that belongs to an `account` (through two foreign keys `recipient_id` and `sender_id`). Each `account` can have many `sources` through a joint table `accounts_sources` (a user can link records of an existing source through that joint table into their own source and write their own data on top of it on the joint record).

The field `address` is a unique identifier used in the `source` (the source representing one implementation of a blockchain) in the format of `0x558ce31604b6df7f936d48c7932a3a8114dd1ddd985a1e9f1f6707456c7744fc`.

I want to make sure that I have no more than one entry for each `transactions.address` and `accounts.address` in each `source`.

How can I add such a constraint to an existing database in Postgres?

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    sender_id uuid NOT NULL,
    recipient_id uuid NOT NULL,
    address character varying NOT NULL
);    

CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    address character varying NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE accounts_sources (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    source_id uuid NOT NULL,
    account_id uuid NOT NULL
);    

CREATE TABLE sources (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY accounts
    ADD CONSTRAINT accounts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY accounts_sources
    ADD CONSTRAINT accounts_sources_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY transactions
    ADD CONSTRAINT transactions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY sources
    ADD CONSTRAINT sources_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY transactions
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_27b65ad5c4 FOREIGN KEY (sender_id) REFERENCES accounts(id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY transactions
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_e3b3f6fd6c FOREIGN KEY (recipient_id) REFERENCES accounts(id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY accounts_sources
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_3825abd5e3 FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES sources(id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY accounts_sources
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_d1c491b354 FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id);
```

Comment: I don't think this can actually be enforced with `CHECK` constraints **as they're implemented now**. This can be checked through triggers, but you should have them in various places (because you have to check when you `INSERT` or `UPDATE` in all involved tables). Very tricky...

Comment: The requirements are not very clear. How can `events.address` and `accounts.address` be unique for a `source` when a source can be related to many accounts and events?

Comment: Plus the DDL is not working. There are extra commas and missing primary keys. @Mike81 please edit the question and 1.correct the DDL s it is working and 2.clarify your requirements.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I've modified the question to better explain the implementation, does it make more sense now? Thanks

Comment: Can the same account be related to two (or more) sources?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, correct. But the address can only exist once per source.

Comment: The model sounds weird then. You seem to want to allow 2 accounts having the same address, as long as they are not related to the same sources. And then, if you try to insert a new account-source relationship, it should be forbidden if that meant the 2 accounts would become related to the same source.

Comment: In all, I don't see how the model matches a block chain model.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks, I'll give it some more thought.